# Can i access Object ID's properties using keys (like in dictionary)?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I am creating a new addon for Blender, and in that addon I need to access Object's properties like **location, scale, etc**. I know that I can access them through interface like: `object.location, object.scale`

It's good if I know what property I need in advance, but I don't know what property I will need to access, it can be location, material of the object, etc. And I need to access them like: `object["location"], object["scale"]`

I tried that way, but I can access only custom properties, not properties like location or scale. Is it possible to access Object's location or material using key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using getattr: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr

```
location = getattr(object, "location")
```